# Get Facebook Post/Photo Url Using Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I created an Facebook app that post my webpage photo on my facebook page by clicking on a button.

Now I also want to show my facebook post url on my webpage.

Means when I'll click on the button on my website, it will publish a photo on facebook and then I want to show that published photo url on my page from facebook.

I'm using this code to publish on facebook:-

```
<?php
require_once("/path-to/facebook_php_sdk/facebook.php"); // set the right path

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'your-app-id';
$config['secret'] = 'your-secret-key;
$config['fileUpload'] = true; // optional
$fb = new Facebook($config);

$params = array(
  "access_token" => "your_access_token",
  "url" => "http://photo-url",
);

try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/fb-page-id/photos', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted photo to Facebook Fan Page';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: please check this link if it will helpful - (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself.

You can use this code to get Facebook post/photo url using fb api

```
try
{
$ret = $fb->api('/fb-page-id/photos', 'POST', $params);
echo 'Successfully posted photo to Facebook Fan Page';
$fbdurl = $ret[post_id];
$url= "https://facebook.com/".$fbdurl;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```